# Looping through a list in a line or getting loop output in flask page

Tags: python

How can i loop through this list inside that bracket so that i can print summary of each name in one run.

```
names = ["Tony Stark", "Will Smith", "LeBron James"]
output = wikipedia.summary(names, sentences=3, auto_suggest=False)
```

I tried these ways

```
(for z in range(10): print(name[z]))
```

```
[name for name in names]
```

i can do it this way but i want to do it in one line

```
names = ["Random guy1", "Random guy2", "Random guy3"]
for name in names:
    output = wikipedia.summary(name, sentences=3, auto_suggest=False)
    print(output)
```

Or simply i want to use that output varibale in my flask file like **{{ output }}** to just run through the name list in python file and give me the output summary in my page.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to send a list of objects to your flask views!!

```
[ wikipedia.summary(name, sentences=3, auto_suggest=False) for name in names]
```

This will give you list of objects

Comment: it didnt work @Sidhar_t.py , it says name not defined on the page

Comment: can you share me your code !!